# Styled Textboxes In Tables

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to create a template for word documents for my University notes.

I downloaded a template for a resume the other day and found this lovely effect where a textbox takes up the entire table cell, and has a lovely blue selection on the outside of it as well as some tooltips (see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qPY1.png) for all this).

My problem is, if I create a bogus table and put a textbox inside the table cell I cannot get the textbox handles to go away. E.g. rotation, resize etc...

I want the textbox to take up the entire cell regardless, instead of resizing with the handles.

I take it this person is using a textbox because the default textbox 'outline' is exactly the same.

**Note:** *The blue outline on "Skills & Abilities" only appears when you mouse into the textbox, the second you click away there is nothing. Just like a default textbox, but without the handles when you focus.*

I also cannot figure out how to get the little tooltips to popup. E.g. in that picture "Category"

Does anybody have any experience here? Googling for a bit came up with nothing.

Comment: What version of Word are you using?

Comment: @mechcow word 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those elements in your screenshot are not actually textboxes, instead they are Content Controls. [This tutorial](http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2010/04/11/add-content-controls-in-the-word-documents-for-the-open-xml-automation/) demonstrates how to manually insert content controls into a document.